# Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem with absolutely continuous measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a locally-compact Hausdorff space and also $(X,\mathcal F, P)$ is a probability space. Let $\psi$ be any positive, linear functional on the space $C_c(X)$ of continuously compactly supported functions $f$ on $X$.

The Riesz-Markov-Kakutani Theorem implies that there exists a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that for all $f \in C_c(X)$,
$$
\psi(f) = \int f(x) d\mu.
$$

Are there conditions that guarantee $\mu \ll P$, so that---by the Radon-Nikodyn theorem---we can write
$$
\psi(f) = \int f(x) \frac{d\mu}{dP} dP \quad ?
$$

Comment: A simple one is if there is a constant $C > 0$ and a $p \in [1,\infty)$ such that $|\psi(f)| \leq C \|f\|_{L^{p}(P)}$, then $\mu \ll P$ and $\frac{d \mu}{dP} \in L^{q}(P)$, where $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$.  I can't think of a convenient way to check whether $\mu \ll P$ in general (i.e. when $\frac{d \mu}{dP} \in L^{1}(P)$ and no better).